# Global template helper undefined on meteor deploy server

Tags: javascript, meteor, helper

I have a file with global function on my Meteor project:

**client/helpers.js**

```
console.log("INIT client helpers")

formatCurrency = function(number, currencyCode) { /* [...] */ }
formatPercentage = function(percent) { /* [...] */ }

Template.registerHelper('formatCurrency', formatCurrency)
Template.registerHelper('formatPercentage', formatPercentage)
```

I use direcly `formatCurrency` function on the client code, and Blaze view. But when I try to deploy on meteor server, I got **Exception in template helper: ReferenceError: formatCurrency is not defined**.
Views are on /client/views/{category}/{view_name}.html, so they are loaded after helper.

On my local server, when I reload the page I got the log on browser console, but not when I hit the prod server.

Do someone know what's the difference ?

-------------[ **UPDATE** ]-------------

Look like the helpers file is just never called by Meteor. If I didn't use any of their function on helper, and load the page it's work. But if I try to call a function (on console), I have a `undefined` error, event 2sec after all the page is ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your load order might be around the wrong way. According to the docs: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp, the views will be loaded first because they have deeper paths (rule 4), which beats alphabetical order (rule 5).

```
HTML template files are always loaded before everything else
Files beginning with main. are loaded last
Files inside any lib/ directory are loaded next
Files with deeper paths are loaded next
Files are then loaded in alphabetical order of the entire path
```

Try putting the global helpers into a "lib" directory (rule 3), such as "client/lib/helpers.js"

Comment: Nothing now when i put helper file on /client/utils... :/

Comment: Okay, look like it's an error with FlowRouter. I have updated my post

Comment: Work with 'lib' but not with 'utils'